# ¿Como agregar a las herramientas la pestaña de reportviewer en Visual Studio 2017 community?

Tags: reportviewer, visual-studio-2017

Estimados.

Lo que dice la pregunta. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de C# donde utilizan Visual studio 2012, donde en la barra de herramientas de la izquierda, tienen toda una categoria llamada "Generador de informes" donde esta la herramienta reportviewer.

Esta categoría no la tengo en visual studio 2017 community.

¿Como puedo agregarla o instalarla?

Saludos

Danilo

Comment: Excelente y muy claro, me sirvió porque tenía el mismo problema, saludos desde Guayaquil-Ecuador

Answer (score 2):

Me auto respondo, ya que encontré la solución.

Con la solución abierta debes entrar a:

> Tools---> Nugget package ----> Package manage console

ahí copiar y pegar lo siguiente

> Install-Package
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms -Pre

y apretar enter.

Hecho esto solo faltará agregar la opción al toolbox o caja de herramientas.

Para esto vamos a algún formulario en modo diseño. Seleccionamos el toolbox y botón derecho en choose item... Una vez dentro le damos a browse y debemos localizar el dll que generamos recién. Este debe estar dentro de la carpeta de tu solución.

Directorio_del_proyecto\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.{version}\lib\net40

debes seleccionar el dll que se llama:

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

Con eso ya tendrás la opción en visual studio 2017

Espero que les sirva.